# Electron non-context-aware native module in renderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have updated electron to latest in my project because there were some printer issues with that now I am facing this problem which is when I am importing packages to frontend it's throwing this error yet this works without any problems yet this bothers me so much I have searched and found this [#1839](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397)
yet I can't find anything or i can't understand what should I do now I have tried

```
app.allowRendererProcessReuse = true;
```

it removes (in the command line) the errors but it stops working completely and throwing big error in frontend can anyone help me with this

> (node:11484) Electron: Loading non-context-aware native module in
>   renderer:
>   '\?\C:\Users\admin\Desktop\co-electronupdate\node_modules@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node'.
>   This is deprecated, see
>   https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397.
>
> (node:11484) Electron: Loading non-context-aware native module in
>   renderer:
>   ''\?\C:\Users\admin\Desktop\co-electronupdate\node_modules@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node'.
>   This is deprecated, see
>   https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397.

as you can see there is a big discussion going still I can't understand i have 2 quetions

1. Should I ignore the error
2. Is there any fix that I can do or should I continue with electron 7.xx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

finally, I found my answer if anyone curious about this here's the [link](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397#issuecomment-583221969)

```
app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false
```

add this line to main.js

Comment: what is the solution then? From the lnk iit not clear to me.

Comment: app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false with electron 9.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Following is the solution for now, until it can't be changed anymore!

```
// Make the following changes in main.js
app.whenReady(() => {
  app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false
})
```

Comment: i didn't have to put the line in the whenReady() callback for it to work (i've put it after the app import)